# Port forwarding over VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-desktop, port-forwarding

Today i was trying to configure RDP.

[image: RDP]

PC2: 192.168.1.10
R1, R2: Mikrotik
VPN is connect over internet

RDP from PC1 to PC2 and from PC3 to PC1 works fine but from PC3 to PC2 through R1 dont work.
I configure forward port 3389 to 192.168.1.10 on R1. SYN packet from PC3 passes to PC2 but SYNACK from PC2 not.

All trafic can trought VPN but i dont know configure it, please help. Sorry for my english.

Comment: The problem with a setup like that is the reverse path. It does not lead over the VPN. // edit: [This](http://backreference.org/2012/10/07/policy-routing-multihoming-and-all-that-jazz/) looks like what you need, but I have no experience with Mikrotik. You essentially have a multi-home situation, where the Internet could be reached either directly or via the VPN tunnel.

Comment: Thanks. I found answer here http://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=73775#p373719 .

Comment: That’s not really the answer though, because it changes how “regular” traffic goes to the Internet. That means everything will pass through R1’s upstream, potentially making everything slow.